# using -force_load linker flag in Xcode causes duplicate symbols error

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, llvm

I'm using two 3rd party frameworks within iOS app Xcode project. One requires the -ObjC other linker flag. The other is incompatible with this flag. I tried using the -force_laod linker flag with the framework that requires the -ObjC flag but I get a ton of duplicate symbol errors. What am I doing wrong here?

The framework that requires the -ObjC linker flag is the FLIROneSDK.
The framework that is incompatible with the -ObjC linker flag is OpenCV.

The error output from the linker is huge so I've only included the first few hundred lines

```
    Ld /Users/Darren_Findlay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cckhkxsawywqouequqrsgmjkwwkp/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug-iphoneos/test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/test normal arm64
    cd /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/Darren_Findlay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cckhkxsawywqouequqrsgmjkwwkp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/Darren_Findlay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cckhkxsawywqouequqrsgmjkwwkp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test -filelist /Users/Darren_Findlay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cckhkxsawywqouequqrsgmjkwwkp/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug-iphoneos/test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/test.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.2 -dead_strip -force_load /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Darren_Findlay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cckhkxsawywqouequqrsgmjkwwkp/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug-iphoneos/test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/test.swiftmodule -lstdc++ -framework Accelerate -framework AssetsLibrary -framework opencv2 -framework FLIROneSDK -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Darren_Findlay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cckhkxsawywqouequqrsgmjkwwkp/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug-iphoneos/test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/test_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Darren_Findlay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cckhkxsawywqouequqrsgmjkwwkp/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug-iphoneos/test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/test

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(pawnrun.o)
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cckhkxsawywqouequqrsgmjkwwkp/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug-iphoneos/test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _jpeg_add_quant_table in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcparam.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_set_quality in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcparam.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_set_defaults in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcparam.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_default_colorspace in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcparam.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_set_colorspace in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcparam.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_idct_float in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jidctflt.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_forward_dct in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcdctmgr.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_idct_ifast in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jidctfst.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_c_main_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcmainct.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_start_compress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapistd.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_write_scanlines in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapistd.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_stdio_src in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdatasrc.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_input_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdinput.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_merged_upsampler in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmerge.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_abort in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcomapi.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_destroy in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcomapi.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_alloc_quant_table in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcomapi.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_alloc_huff_table in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcomapi.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_stdio_dest in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdatadst.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_marker_writer in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcmarker.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_idct_islow in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jidctint.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_calc_output_dimensions in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmaster.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_master_decompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmaster.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_fdct_float in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jfdctflt.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_read_coefficients in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdtrans.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_d_coef_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdcoefct.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_get_small in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jmemnobs.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_free_small in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jmemnobs.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_get_large in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jmemnobs.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_free_large in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jmemnobs.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_mem_available in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jmemnobs.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_open_backing_store in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jmemnobs.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_mem_init in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jmemnobs.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_mem_term in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jmemnobs.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_c_coef_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jccoefct.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_fdct_ifast in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jfdctfst.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_color_converter in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jccolor.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_c_master_control in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcmaster.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_color_deconverter in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdcolor.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_idct_4x4 in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jidctred.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_idct_2x2 in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jidctred.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_idct_1x1 in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jidctred.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_phuff_decoder in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdphuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_inverse_dct in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jddctmgr.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_c_prep_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcprepct.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_std_error in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jerror.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_std_message_table in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jerror.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_make_d_derived_tbl in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdhuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_fill_bit_buffer in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdhuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_huff_decode in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdhuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_huff_decoder in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdhuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_memory_mgr in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jmemmgr.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_CreateDecompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_destroy_decompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_abort_decompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_read_header in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_consume_input in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_finish_decompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jdiv_round_up in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jutils.o)
duplicate symbol _jround_up in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jutils.o)
duplicate symbol _jcopy_sample_rows in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jutils.o)
duplicate symbol _jcopy_block_row in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jutils.o)
duplicate symbol _jzero_far in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jutils.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_natural_order in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jutils.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_1pass_quantizer in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jquant1.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_d_post_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdpostct.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_d_main_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmainct.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_start_decompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapistd.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_read_scanlines in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapistd.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_resync_to_restart in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmarker.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_marker_reader in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmarker.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_set_marker_processor in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmarker.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_make_c_derived_tbl in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jchuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_gen_optimal_table in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jchuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_huff_encoder in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jchuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_upsampler in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdsample.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_fdct_islow in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jfdctint.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_2pass_quantizer in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jquant2.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_downsampler in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcsample.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_CreateCompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_destroy_compress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_suppress_tables in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_finish_compress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_compress_master in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcinit.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_phuff_encoder in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcphuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_write_coefficients in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jctrans.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_copy_critical_parameters in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jctrans.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_CreateCompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_destroy_compress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_suppress_tables in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_finish_compress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_start_compress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapistd.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_write_scanlines in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcapistd.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_c_coef_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jccoefct.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_color_converter in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jccolor.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_forward_dct in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcdctmgr.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_make_c_derived_tbl in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jchuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_gen_optimal_table in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jchuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_huff_encoder in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jchuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_compress_master in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcinit.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_c_main_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcmainct.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_marker_writer in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcmarker.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_c_master_control in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcmaster.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_abort in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcomapi.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_destroy in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcomapi.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_alloc_quant_table in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcomapi.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_alloc_huff_table in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcomapi.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_add_quant_table in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcparam.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_set_quality in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcparam.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_set_defaults in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcparam.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_default_colorspace in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcparam.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_set_colorspace in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcparam.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_phuff_encoder in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcphuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_c_prep_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcprepct.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_downsampler in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jcsample.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_write_coefficients in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jctrans.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_copy_critical_parameters in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jctrans.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_CreateDecompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_destroy_decompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_abort_decompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_read_header in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_consume_input in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_finish_decompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapimin.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_start_decompress in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapistd.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_read_scanlines in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdapistd.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_stdio_dest in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdatadst.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_stdio_src in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdatasrc.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_d_coef_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdcoefct.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_color_deconverter in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdcolor.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_inverse_dct in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jddctmgr.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_make_d_derived_tbl in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdhuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_fill_bit_buffer in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdhuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_huff_decode in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdhuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_huff_decoder in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdhuff.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_input_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdinput.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_d_main_controller in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmainct.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_resync_to_restart in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmarker.o)
duplicate symbol _jinit_marker_reader in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmarker.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_set_marker_processor in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmarker.o)
duplicate symbol _jpeg_calc_output_dimensions in:
    /Users/Darren_Findlay/Desktop/test/test/FLIROneSDK.framework/Versions/A/FLIROneSDK(jdmaster.o)
```

Comment: which library you are using?

Comment: What are the duplicate symbols?

Comment: Hmmm, the interesting one is `_main`.  I do not understand why there would be a `main()` in a framework object file.  About the other (JPEG) related symnols; they are showing only one object file using them, so that's strange.   That `FLIROneSDK.framework` looks pretty broken. I guess there is no way you could throw it away and do without it?

Comment: HI trojanfoe. Unfortunately thats not an option. The FLIROneSDK is shipped with the FLIR One thermal camera accessory and is required to develop apps to use this hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got a reply from the guys who made the FLIROneSDK and basically they said its a known issue. OpenCV (and a number of other libraries) cannot be used in the same project as FLIROneSDK due to an issue in the SDK.

Comment: The issue being it's broken.

Comment: The FLIROneSDK works fine without the presence of OpenCV. But yeah its a major issue so I'd agree with calling it broken.